# Edit compile and run cycle

Tags: makeprg, filetype-c

I've just got the hang of the wonders of `:make` and the ability to cycle through the errors. Obviously, I have to do a `set makeprg` with the settings I need and everything is nice, but the problem is that I don't know how to run.

Basically, the problem is that I got used to something like

`:!pushd build && make && popd && ./build/bin/run --args`

I want to get the quickfix list populated if there are errors, and if there are not, to be able to run the program **in the same command**. Is there any way of achieving this? Obviously, the question is for `C/C++` projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the `makeprg` set up correctly:

```
let &l:makeprg = 'cd build && make'
```

The `&l:` syntax for `let` sets local variables; you can also use `setlocal` but then you need to use backslashes, which is annoying.

You can make a command or keybind which 1) runs `:make` or `:makel`, which either populates or clears the quickfix window or locallist, and 2) runs your program if the quickfix window and locallist are empty.

Personally I like my `MM` mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> MM :silent! :wa<CR>:echo &makeprg<CR>:silent make<CR>:redraw!<CR>
```

To extend that we can add a new `b:run` variable which contains a shell command to run. You probably want to set this from an autocmd as the commands are probably different per-project, and then add something like this to the mapping:

```
:exe get(b:, 'run') isnot 0 && len(getqflist() + getloclist('')) is 0 ? '!' .. b:run : ''<CR>
```

`getqflist()` gets the quickfix list, and `getloclist('')` gets the location list for the current buffer. Only of both are empty and `b:run` is set do we run the command.

Putting it all together:

```
augroup run
  au!
  au BufNewFile,BufReadPost /path/to/my/project/*.c
           \ let &l:makeprg = 'cd build && make'
           \ let b:run = './build/bin/run --args'
augroup end

nnoremap <silent> MM :silent! :wa<CR>:echo &makeprg<CR>:silent make<CR>:redraw!<CR>:exe get(b:, 'run') isnot 0 && len(getqflist() + getloclist('')) is 0 ? '!' .. b:run : ''<CR>
```

That mapping becomes a bit ... much, so you can also put it as a command + mapping, or function + mapping:

```
command -nargs=* Make
    \  silent! :wa
    \| echo &makeprg
    \| silent make <args>
    \| redraw!
    \| exe get(b:, 'run') isnot 0 && len(getqflist() + getloclist('')) is 0 ? '!' .. b:run : ''

nnoremap <silent> MM :Make<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

At this moment detecting whether the compilation has successfully ended to chain with something else requires scripting.

For more detailed explanations/example, see this SO Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988941/vim-mapping-for-running-c-with-optional-input-file/56991040#56991040

Note: we can trick Vim with `:make %< && ./%< which` will also send the execution results into the quickfix window. I've never tested it with interactive programs (i.e. that read from stdin/std::cin).

Answer (score 1):

You can just add running the program to the `Makefile` as a target: for example, one named `run`. Then you just `:make run`.
`run` has a dependency on the program, to make sure that the program is created or updated before execution:

```
.PHONY: run
run: $(the_program)
        ./$(the_program) $(run_args)
```

Arguments can be passed to it via the Makefile variable, e.g.

```
:make run run_args=...
```

The quoting there (separate topic) can be tricky if you have arguments with spaces.

If `$(the_program)` is out-of-date, and the attempt to build it results in errors, then of course the `run` recipe will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, similar to what Kaz outlined before, but even simpler. Simply add a target to your executable with the appropriate requirements:

```
build/bin/run:  1.cpp
    g++ -Wall $< -o $@ && ./$@
```

`$<` refers to the first requirement and `$@` points to the target (in this case, `build/bin/run`).

Now type `:make` in vim. If there are no errors, the output will be shown in vim's pager. When there are no changes in the dependency graph, `make` will show you `'build/bin/run' is up to date.`  and when there are errors, those will populate the quickfix list automatically. You might need to add an appropriate `errorformat` string (e.g. `:set errorformat=%E%f:%l:%c:%m,%-G%.%#` for g++) to show one error per line.

For a more ergonomic workflow, you might want to add the following keybinding `:nnoremap <silent> <leader>m :w<cr>:make<cr>:cw<cr>`, which shows the quickfix window only when there are errors.